MarianDB upgrade issue from 10.3 to 10.7 but 11
Bit of an issue
The server downloaded MarianDB 11 but only want to upgrade to 10.11
Any Help
yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * epel: cdn.centos.no
 * extras: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
 * remi-php82: cdn.centos.no
 * remi-safe: cdn.centos.no
 * updates: mirror.freethought-internet.co.uk
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.3.39-1.el7.centos will be updated
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.11.7-1.el7.centos will be an update
--> Processing Conflict: MariaDB-client-11.3.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts MariaDB-server < 11.0.0
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: MariaDB-client conflicts with MariaDB-server-10.11.7-1.el7.centos.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 4 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
MariaDB-client-11.3.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64 has installed conflicts MariaDB-server < ('0', '11.0.0', None): MariaDB-server-10.3.39-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-common-11.3.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64 has installed conflicts MariaDB-server < ('0', '10.6.1', None): MariaDB-server-10.3.39-1.el7.centos.x86_64
MariaDB-server-10.3.39-1.el7.centos.x86_64 has missing requires of galera
MariaDB-server-compat-11.3.2-1.el7.centos.noarch has missing requires of MariaDB-server >= ('0', '11.0.0', None)


What is your repo configuration file/line? FWIW - I just followed the instructions and got a 10.11 installed.
